# .htaccess rewrite/redirect on existing subdirectory back to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I only want to ignore rewrite rules for existing files. Pretty much any other access to this website is though the root index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^\/]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Hence, even a directory that exists should be pointed to root index.php, unless it's pointing to an existing file in that directory.

Works great if the subfolder doesn't exist, but I'm getting some odd behavior on folders that exist. The content of index.php loads, but then all the relative links therein breaks because the client browser acts like it's in the subfolder.

E.g. the folder `data` exists, so when you got to `website.com/data`, it routes to `website.com/data/index.php?p=data` instead of just `website.com/index.php?p=data` and the site breaks because it's looking for `website.com/data/build/scripts.js` instead of `website.com/build/scripts.js`.

Is my RewriteBase wrong or just doesn't work that way with existing subdirs? Do I need to do a hard redirect if calling a subdir that exists?

Comment: add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: *Slaps head* way simpler than looking into more htaccess stuff, thanks!